# Pass data using a loop into Metadata Injection Step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to pass data using metadata injection. The target step has 2 table input steps and a dimension lookup update step.

This needs to happen as a loop going over 100 tables or so.

Currently, I am trying to use a Data grid step. One column has the MYSQL code for the first table input in the target KTR. The second column has the MYSQL code for the second KTR. The 3rd column has the target table name (for the Dimension Lookup/Update step.). The last column contains all the fields which are going to be mapped. So if the first 3 columns have only 1 row the 4th column would have a lot more so I can be able to pass the fields to the Dimension Lookup/Update step. Note that the fields in which I am passing have the same name always.

My question is how can I loop through all 100 or so tables? Is this method appropriate and if it is not does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I loop through all 100 or so tables?

[Metadata Injection](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Products/ETL_metadata_injection) step is the recommended way to iterate through 100+ tables. Alternatively you can also use "copy rows to results" approach to iterate through. The details of using copy rows to result can be found in [this blog post](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/).

> Is this method appropriate and if it is not does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Based on your question and approach, Pentaho expects the fields to be mapped before looping for the dimensional lookup step. So if you are trying to dynamically pass the fields, unfortunately, that won't work. Your approach of looping through tables will work fine only if the fields across all of those tables are consistent and mapped correctly in the step.

Alternatively, you can use [Execute SQL](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Execute_SQL_Script) step. However in this case you can dynamically send the fields and the table names too. The only downside is you need to construct the dimensional lookup / SCD-II logic in an SQL statement.